# ApiPlatform without response with pagination=false

Tags: php, rest, symfony, nginx, api-platform.com

I have an entity Localita (with ~7000 records) mapped with API Platform bundle, with these annotations:

```
@ApiResource(
  attributes={
      "normalization_context"={"groups"={"read"}},
      "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"write"}},
      "filters"={"localita.search_filter"},
      "pagination_client_enabled"={"true"}
      },
  itemOperations={
      "get"={"method"="GET"},
      "put"={"method"="PUT"}
      },
  collectionOperations={
      "get"={"method"="GET"}
      }
  )
```

As you can see, I've enabled pagination_client_enabled feature.
So, if I call via GET request

```
curl -X GET "http://myserver/app_dev.php/rest/localitas" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

I obtain first 30 records, ok! It's great!
But, if I call with pagination=false

```
curl -X GET "http://serpa.local/app_dev.php/rest/localitas?pagination=false" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

I obtain blank page without any response.
Opening browser console, I see a 500 error code, without errors in all log files (nginx, symfony, php).

Why??

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was php-fpm memory_limit setting... too low.

It has crashed without any warning...